# What does "scary ones, besides the waist" mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

A quote from a [TED presentation](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iE9HMudybyc&list=PLua6pzs27dr-8LcGht9GjkjAlidA_JCNT&index=13) at 58 second:

> Of course, there's health consequences to this, **scary ones, besides the waist.**

What does the bold text mean? Was she talking about the foot or something that's below the waist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

She's talking about how people sit too much and generally lack physical activity. The quote in more context:

> In a way, sitting has become the smoking of our generation. **And of
> course, there's health consequences to this: scary ones, besides the
> waist.** Things like breast cancer and colon cancer are directly tied to our lack of physical activity.

What she means by the part in bold is that there are lots of health consequences to sitting down so much. Those health consequences are *scary*. And there's more than just what you're all thinking: gaining weight / getting fatter around the waist, where most people carry a lot of their fat. That's the "besides the waist" part.

In other words:

*... And of course, there are health consequences to sitting down so much. There are scary consequences; consequences even worse than just gaining fat around the waist. Besides getting fatter bellies, you can also develop cancers from your lack of physical activity...*

That's the idea anyway. (Also I just listened to the snippet, so I don't have the full context. I'm assuming she meant "besides people getting fatter around the midsection" as "besides the waist". It makes sense contextually.)